# Multivariable Chain Rule Doubt

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Im learning Partial differential Equations now ( introductory course ). While in calculus course I have learnt that ,

> If $f=f(x,y,z)$ where $x,y,z$ are independent variables then,
> $$df=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz$$ in case $f=f(x,y,z)$ and $x=x(u,v)$, $y=y(u,v)$, $z=z(u,v)$ where $u,v$ are independent variables.
>
> then, $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial u}$$ but in case of PDE formulation of the eq. $$f(x,y,z,a,b)=0\tag{$\circledast$}$$ where $a,b$ are arbitrary constant
>
> How can I differentiate $\circledast$ w.r.t. $x$ because here $z$ is not independent variable but $z=z(x,y)$.

Im aware of the proof for multivariable chain rule in case of 2 independent variables variables I know same can be extrapolated to 3 independent variables

Comment: Where's it written that $z$ is a function of $x$ and $y$? It is clearly written $z$ is an independent variable.

Comment: Please see the last equation

Comment: In that z=z(x,y)

Comment: $\frac{df}{dx}=f_x+f_zz_x$

Comment: Can u say how did u get that?

Comment: In your formula where $x=x(u,v),y=y(u,v),z=z(u,v)$ simply substitute $u=x,v=y$ and remember $\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0$ due to independence.

Comment: Then what will the meaning of x=x(x,y) if we substitute u =x and v=y

Comment: Context matters here. Is $z=z(x,y)$ a separate condition from $f(\cdots)=0$ that *also* apples, or is it just the result of solving the $f$ equation for z? In other words, does $f(x,y,z(x,y),a,b)=0$ hold for all pairs $(x,y)$ in a region?

Comment: Z=Z(x,y) is not a separate condition its just the one you get solving f(....)=0 . In that case ,can you explain the rule for partially differentiating w.r.t x the above eq i.e. f(...)=0 on both the sides.

Comment: $z$ is implicitly defined by $f=0$, you are looking for implicit differentiation.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, recall [implicit differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/implicit_differentiation) from single variable calculus. If you have an equation like $x^3+y^2-64=0$, then you can think of $y$ as an implicit function of $x$, and differentiate both sides with respect to $x$ using the chain rule: $3x^2+2y\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=0$ so that $\dfrac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=-\dfrac{3x^2}{2y}$, which holds whether or not $y=\sqrt{64-x^3}$ or $y=-\sqrt{64-x^3}$ (as long as $y\ne 0$).

Your situation is the same thing, just with more variables. If $z$ is an implicit function of $x$ and $y$, then we can use the chain rule to write $0=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial a}\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial b}\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}$. But $\dfrac{\partial a}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial b}{\partial x}$ are $0$ because $a$ and $b$ are constants, and $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0$ since $x$ and $y$ are our independent variables. So this reduces to  $0=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}$ so that $\dfrac{\partial z}{\partial x}=\dfrac{-\partial f/\partial x}{\partial f/\partial z}$.